# ++ a number when two outputs are the same

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tales game where you select heads or tails and then the computer will select heads or tails and then a random output will be put on the screen if you selected the right one it will add one point to you or the  computer or both the first one to five wins. I'm having problem adding the points to ‘thePlayersPoints’  and ‘theComputerPoints’. The outcome I what is where when they equal it will add a point. but what's happening is because it's a click function is it will only Add them  if the value is already on the page. What I mean is if you click heads an heads comes up it won't add it until you click it again.
The function that tries to add the points start at line 67.

```js
//Btns
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let HeadsBtn = document.querySelector('.heads')
let TailsBtn = document.querySelector('.talis')
let output = document.querySelector('.output')

//Player
let PlayersChoice = document.querySelector('.PlayersChoice')
let ThePlayersPoints = document.querySelector('.ThePlayersPoints')
//computer
let ComputerChoice = document.querySelector('.ComputerChoice')
let TheComputersPoints = document.querySelector('.TheComputersPoints')
//winner
let winner = document.querySelector('.winner')
//headsAndTails
let player = 0
let computer = 0



//get The output.
let btnContaner = document.querySelector('.btnCon')
btnContaner.addEventListener('click', pinkingOne)
function pinkingOne(TheOutput){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)

    if(random  === 0){
        TheOutput = 'Tails'
    }else{
        TheOutput = 'Heads'
    }
  
    output.innerText = `${ TheOutput}`
}


//Adds Heads  to Player selected.
 HeadsBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    PlayersChoice.innerHTML  = 'Heads'
   
})

//Adds Tails to Player selected.
TailsBtn.addEventListener('click',function(pick){
   pick ='Tails' 
    PlayersChoice.innerHTML = `${pick}` 
})


    //computers pinking heads or tails
    btnContaner.addEventListener('click',computersPick)
    function computersPick(pick){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    if(random === 1){
    pick = 'Heads'
    }else{
    pick = 'Talis'
    }
    ComputerChoice.innerText = `${pick}`
    }



 //adding the points to the player and computer

 HeadsBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
     if(PlayersChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML){
         ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML++
     }else{
         if (ComputerChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML){
            TheComputersPoints.innerHTML++
         }
     }
 })

 TailsBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(PlayersChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML){
        ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML++
    }else{
        if (ComputerChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML){
           TheComputersPoints.innerHTML++
        }
    }
})
 //^^^^^^^adding the points to the player and computer ^^^^^^^^






    //outputing the winner.
    function andTheWinnerIs(){
        let Tbtn = document.querySelector('#Tails')
        let Hbtn = document.querySelector('#Heads')
       Tbtn.addEventListener('click',addforplayer)
       Hbtn.addEventListener('click',addforplayer)
       //outputing the winner
         if ( ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML == 5 &&  TheComputersPoints.innerHTML == 5){
            winner.innerHTML = `It's a Tie`;
        } else if (ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML == 5){
            winner.innerHTML = `You Win!!!`;
        } else if (TheComputersPoints.innerHTML == 5){
            winner.innerHTML = `Computer Wins!!!`;
        }

    }
```

```css
html{
    background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.712);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:0;

}

body {
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
  }

.PlayerSelected{
position: relative;
right: 150px;
font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;


}

.ComputerSelected{
position: relative;
left: 150px;
top: -43px;
font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
}

.PlayerPoints{
    position: relative;
    left: -110px;
    top:109px;
    font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.ComputerPoints{
    position: relative;
    right: -103px;
    top: 60px;
    font-family: 'Quantico';
}


.PlayersChoice{
    color: rgba(19, 107, 207, 0.836);
    background-color: black;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -80px;
    top: -37px
}

#Theoutput{
    font-size:xx-large;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px

    
}

#ThePlayersPoints{
    position: relative;
    top:23.5px;
    width:10px;
    left:-75px;
    font-family: 'Quantico';
}


#TheComputersPoints{
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: -5px;
    font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.ComputerChoice{
    position: relative;
    right: -250px;
    color:red;
    top: -90px
}



#Thewinner{
    background-color:aqua;

    width: 200px;
}


.H1{
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.589);
}


#Heads{
outline: none;
border: none;
font-size: xx-large;
cursor: pointer;
}

#Tails{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: xx-large;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Tails:hover{
   font-size: 50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 26, 255, 0.534);
    box-shadow: 5px 10px gray;
}

#Heads:hover{
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.664);
    box-shadow: -5px 10px gray;
}

.pickHeadsOrTalis{
    font-family: 'Staatliches';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Light Switching</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap');
        </style>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quantico&display=swap');
            </style>
            <style>
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap');
                </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1 class='H1'>First Player to 5 points wins!</h1>
<h3 class='PlayerSelected'>Player selected:</h3>
<div id='PlayersChoice' id='o' class='PlayersChoice'></div>
 <h3  class='ComputerSelected' >Computer selected:</h3>
 <div id='ComputerChoice'  class='ComputerChoice '></div>

<h4 class='PlayerPoints' >Player:</h4>
   <h4 class='ComputerPoints'> Computer: </h4>

<div class="PlayersAndComputersPoints">
   <div id='ThePlayersPoints' class="ThePlayersPoints">0</div> 
    <div id='TheComputersPoints'  class="TheComputersPoints">0</div>
</div>

<div id='Theoutput' class="output"></div>
<h1 id='Thewinner' class="winner"></h1>

<h1 class="pickHeadsOrTalis">Pick heads or tails?</h1>

<div id='allBtn' class="btnCon">
<button id='Heads' class="heads">Heads</button>   <button id='Tails'  class='talis'>Tails</button>
</div>

</center>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see the buttons in your snippet. Remove the `overflow:hidden;` on the body so that you can scroll to the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are adding in two different `'click'` event listeners in the buttons and they should be combined into one.

Secondly the `if` statement in the second event listener will only ever get to evaluate the computer's choice **if** the player's choice doesn't match. You need to remove the `else` between the player evaluation and the computer's evaluation and just do two different `if` statements for each player.

You also had two extra unneeded event listeners on the `.btnContainer` element. You can just call those functions all in the one button click event.

You will also want to disable the buttons after a game is won and add in a reset button to start the game over.

I hope that this helps

See snippet below for the changes I made:

```js
//Btns
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let HeadsBtn = document.querySelector('.heads')
let TailsBtn = document.querySelector('.talis')
let output = document.querySelector('.output')

//Player
let PlayersChoice = document.querySelector('.PlayersChoice')
let ThePlayersPoints = document.querySelector('.ThePlayersPoints')
//computer
let ComputerChoice = document.querySelector('.ComputerChoice')
let TheComputersPoints = document.querySelector('.TheComputersPoints')
//winner
let winner = document.querySelector('.winner')
//headsAndTails
let player = 0
let computer = 0



//get The output.
let btnContaner = document.querySelector('.btnCon')
//btnContaner.addEventListener('click', pinkingOne)

function pinkingOne() {
  let TheOutput;
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)

  if (random === 0) {
    TheOutput = 'Tails'
  } else {
    TheOutput = 'Heads'
  }

  output.innerText = `${ TheOutput}`
}


//Adds Heads  to Player selected.
// HeadsBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
//PlayersChoice.innerHTML  = 'Heads'

//})

//Adds Tails to Player selected.
//TailsBtn.addEventListener('click',function(pick){
//   pick ='Tails' 
//    PlayersChoice.innerHTML = `${pick}` 
//})


//computers pinking heads or tails
//btnContaner.addEventListener('click',computersPick)

function computersPick() {
  let pick;
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
  if (random === 1) {
    pick = 'Heads'
  } else {
    pick = 'Tails'
  }
  ComputerChoice.innerText = `${pick}`
}



//adding the points to the player and computer

HeadsBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  PlayersChoice.innerHTML = 'Heads'
  pinkingOne();
  computersPick();
  if (PlayersChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML) {
    player++
    ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML = player;
  }
  // else {
  if (ComputerChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML) {
    computer++
    TheComputersPoints.innerHTML = computer
  }
  //}
  if (player === 5 || computer === 5) {
    andTheWinnerIs();
  }
})

TailsBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  PlayersChoice.innerHTML = 'Tails'
  pinkingOne();
  computersPick();
  if (PlayersChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML) {
    player++
    ThePlayersPoints.innerHTML = player;
  }
  // else {
  if (ComputerChoice.innerHTML === output.innerHTML) {
    computer++
    TheComputersPoints.innerHTML = computer
  }
  //}
  if (player === 5 || computer === 5) {
    andTheWinnerIs();
  }
})
//^^^^^^^adding the points to the player and computer ^^^^^^^^






//outputing the winner.
function andTheWinnerIs() {
  //let Tbtn = document.querySelector('#Tails')
  //let Hbtn = document.querySelector('#Heads')
  //Tbtn.addEventListener('click', addforplayer)
  //Hbtn.addEventListener('click', addforplayer)
  //outputing the winner
  if (player === 5 && computer == 5) {
    winner.innerHTML = `It's a Tie`;
  } else if (player === 5) {
    winner.innerHTML = `You Win!!!`;
  } else if (computer === 5) {
    winner.innerHTML = `Computer Wins!!!`;
  }

}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.712);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  /* overflow: hidden;
  Hide scrollbars */
}

.PlayerSelected {
  position: relative;
  right: 150px;
  font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
}

.ComputerSelected {
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  top: -43px;
  font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif;
}

.PlayerPoints {
  position: relative;
  left: -110px;
  top: 109px;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.ComputerPoints {
  position: relative;
  right: -103px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.PlayersChoice {
  color: rgba(19, 107, 207, 0.836);
  background-color: black;
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: -80px;
  top: -37px
}

#Theoutput {
  font-size: xx-large;
  position: relative;
  top: -120px
}

#ThePlayersPoints {
  position: relative;
  top: 23.5px;
  width: 10px;
  left: -75px;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

#TheComputersPoints {
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  top: -5px;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.ComputerChoice {
  position: relative;
  right: -250px;
  color: red;
  top: -90px
}

#Thewinner {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 200px;
}

.H1 {
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.589);
}

#Heads {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: xx-large;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Tails {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: xx-large;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Tails:hover {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 26, 255, 0.534);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px gray;
}

#Heads:hover {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.664);
  box-shadow: -5px 10px gray;
}

.pickHeadsOrTalis {
  font-family: 'Staatliches';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Light Switching</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap');
  </style>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quantico&display=swap');
  </style>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1 class='H1'>First Player to 5 points wins!</h1>
    <h3 class='PlayerSelected'>Player selected:</h3>
    <div id='PlayersChoice' id='o' class='PlayersChoice'></div>
    <h3 class='ComputerSelected'>Computer selected:</h3>
    <div id='ComputerChoice' class='ComputerChoice '></div>

    <h4 class='PlayerPoints'>Player:</h4>
    <h4 class='ComputerPoints'> Computer: </h4>

    <div class="PlayersAndComputersPoints">
      <div id='ThePlayersPoints' class="ThePlayersPoints">0</div>
      <div id='TheComputersPoints' class="TheComputersPoints">0</div>
    </div>

    <div id='Theoutput' class="output"></div>
    <h1 id='Thewinner' class="winner"></h1>

    <h1 class="pickHeadsOrTalis">Pick heads or tails?</h1>

    <div id='allBtn' class="btnCon">
      <button id='Heads' class="heads">Heads</button> <button id='Tails' class='talis'>Tails</button>
    </div>

  </center>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```